# Prevent React from Rendering Child in Functional Component

Tags: reactjs

I have tried `React.memo` and `shouldComponentUpdate`. So far nothing has worked.

Here is my code:

```
function JobEditPage() {
    const [barMessage, setBarMessage] = useState(false);

    return 
    <Parent>
        <DisplayJobContent handleBarMessage={setBarMessage}/>
        <EditJobContent handleBarMessage={setBarMessage}/>
        <Bar massage={barMessage} />
    </Parent>
}

function DisplayJobContent(props) {
   const [value, setValue] = useState();

   submit() {
       ...
       handleBarMessage('Job Content Submitted');
   }

   function ApprovedJob() {}

   function ActiveJob() {
       return <Textfield value={value} ... />
   }

   return
      <div>
         { props.jobStatus > 4 ? 
               <ApprovedJob />
                :
               <ActiveJob />
         }          
      </div>
}
```

**Problem** `DisplayJobContent` renders everytime when `setBarMessage` is called. How can I prevent this from rendering because I don't want to clear the `<Textfield value />`?

Comment: you have two solutions, 
1. change the value state outside DisplayJobContent and pass it as props , 
2. using a global state for saving your previous Textfield value

Comment: `React.memo` will prevent it from rendering if the props don't change

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing value of `barMessage`. Then, obviously the child components will be rerendered since you are sending that datas in props. It is React's default behaviour.

Solution : **Context**

To fix this issue. You can create a context for all these components and share the states between these components. So that, even `barMessage` state value changes `value` state values remains the same.

Comment: Only the callback is being passed as a parameter. Would React still re-render even if it's just the callback? Thanx

Comment: Yes. That callback will change the state in parent component. So the parent component re renders here. Then obviously the child component inside the parent component also re renders.

Comment: Hmmm, I found out what my issue was. I was still able to pass the `setBarMessage` and `barMessage` and the state is still preserved.

Comment: May I know, How did you do that ?

Comment: look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what my issue was!

Calling the Functional components inside 'EditJobContent` was causing a rerender.

In other Words.

The Code Below Causes a Rerender.

```
export default function App(props) {
     
     function subComponentOne() { 
          return <contentsOne props />
     }
     
     function subComponentTwo() {
          return <contentsTwo props />
     }

     return (
          { conditional ? 
                 <subComponentOne />
                  :
                 <subComponentTwo />
          }
     )
}
```

THis is how I was I changed and it worked.

```
export default function App(props) {
     
     function subComponentOne() {}
     
     function subComponentTwo() {}

     return (
           <React.Fragment />
                { conditional ? 
                 <contentsOne props/>
                  :
                 <contentsTwo props />
                }
           <React.Fragment />
      )
}
```